# Ocelot API Gateway

Tags: javascript, angular, .net-core

I had problem. I had installed latest Ocelot version (16.0.1) in API gateway project, which didn't work.
This was fixed when I downgraded my Ocelot version to 15.0.6. My .NET Core sdk version is still 3.1.
I'm not sure if other versions between 15.0.6 work, and then I have downgraded the version to this specific version that's work properly please let me know.

It seems to me that at least something missing in the latest Ocelot version.

Comment: aaand what was the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Ocelot upgrade to major version 16 changed the main configuration property name in the ocelot.json

Instead "ReRoutes" use "Routes".